# Final Destination address in Customs and Immigration form for F1 students

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, paperwork

My friend has an F1 visa for IIT Chicago and is travelling from Mumbai to Chicago. He will have a layover in New York for ten days, after which he will continue his journey to Chicago. He already has the New York to Chicago flight ticket booked.

He has to fill out a Customs and Immigration form at port of entry, which is New York.

What should be the U.S. Street Address in the Customs form to be submitted at New York? 
Does it have to be the port of entry of immigrant or the final destination (university housing) address?

Answer (score 4):

Neither. The [CBP](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/sample-declaration-form) guidance notes say:

> Print your current street address in the United States. If you are staying at a hotel, include the hotel's name and street address. Print the city and the state in the appropriate boxes.

Where your friend expects to be 10 days later is not *current* and that in your friend's case the port of entry happens to be in the same state may be considered as coincidence. Your friend should apply the address of the first accommodation expected to be occupied by your friend on arrival in USA.

In this context a quote from [BA](http://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/passports-visas-and-api) may be of interest:

> Additionally, on US flights, you will be asked for:
>
> •  the destination address of your first night’s stay